# Prevent app from App Store update

Tags: applications, mac-appstore, software-update

I have two versions of Xcode, one is the latest Xcode 5 and the old 4.6.3.
The second one is just a copy of the first one, just before the App Store update.
But after the update, App Store keeps telling me to upgrade Xcode again.

Is there any option to turn off this feature for a separate app or folder?
I really want to use the new Maverick auto update feature, but it will update my old Xcode and i really need that iOS5 Simulator....

UPD: Yes i had iOS 5.0 and 5.1 simulator on **Mountain Lion**, but not or **Mavericks**...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I no longer got notification form updates, maybe because i set the two older Xcode to locked... maybe not.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If iOS5 simulator is your only concern for not upgrading to XCode 5, then you don't have to worry. The XCode 5 supports iOS5 simulator too. Just you have to download. See the picture. It is found in the Xcode-->Preferences.

And I do not think there is any option for not to auto update.

[image]

Comment: For OSX Mountain Lion there is 5.0 and 5.1 Simulator, but on Mavericks i no longer can download it.